# Irreducible elements in a factor ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Here is the problem 11.2.16 from Artin, *Algebra*:

> $F$ is a field. Let  $R$ be the ring $$\frac {F[u,v,y,x_1,x_2,x_3,...]}{(x_1y-uv,x{_2}{^2}-x_1,x{_3}{^2}-x_2,...)}.$$ Show that $u,v$ are irreducible elements in $R$.

1. The above problem can be diverted into the problem as follow:

$$R=\frac {F[u,v,y,x_1,...,x_n]}{(x_1y-uv,x{_2}{^2}-x_1,...,x{_n}{^2}-x_{n-1})}.$$
Show that $u$ is irreducible in $R$.

2. Since $$\frac {F[x_1,...,x_n]}{(x{_2}{^2}-x_1,...,x{_n}{^2}-x_{n-1})}=F[x]$$ by sending $x_i$ to $x^{2^{n-i}}$, $$R=\frac {F[u,v,y,x]}{(x^{2^{n-1}}y-uv)}.$$ Then I am stuck in the process to deal with the form as follow:
   $$u+p_1p_2=q(x^{2^{n-1}}y-uv)$$where $p_1,p_2,q\in F[u,v,x,y]$.
3. Maybe it is easier to firstly deal with $\dfrac {F[u,v,x,y]}{(xy-uv)}$. So is $\dfrac {F[u,v,x,y]}{(xy-uv)}$ isomorphic to a familiar ring we've know?
4. Maybe there exists another way to solve the problem. I expect your ideas. Thank you.

Comment: You are on the right track. For a proof that $x$ is irreducible in $F[u,v,x,y]/(xy-uv)$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/500658/121097).

Comment: @user26857  Why is $F[u,v,x,y]/(xy-uv)$ a integer ring.

Comment: If by "integer ring" you mean an integral domain, then use that $xy-uv$ is irreducible. But take care, this ring is not isomorphic to any "familiar ring".

Comment: @user26857  If $R[u,v,x,y]$ is UFD, then we can say so. If not, how do we use "$xy-uv$ is irreducible" ?

Comment: @user26857 Is $F[x_1, ..., x_n]$ a UFD, where F is a field?

Comment: @user26857 I don't know how to solve the problem with your hint.

Comment: Yes, $F[x_1, ..., x_n]$ is an UFD.

Comment: @user26857  How to prove it?

Comment: Every textbook in algebra does it. Probably Artin, too.